# Getting parenthood of tree structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I am trying to retrieve a tree structure i want specific levels of 'parenthood'. my table has level of depth, pathIndex and mapping. my first approach was to make some kinds of substrings to be able to look for the value via the mapping, but I am getting multiple errors on conversion of strings. one thing that might be possible is that if i try and query an item that is not at the lowest level it should return null for the levels it is missing.

In the table if i where to query for the line while asterisks

```
Id                                     depth    pathindex   ItemNumber
4CF91F7F-832E-468D-B44A-E14DC66E710A     0          0        0.0
D34784A3-2134-4D09-828E-0EDA0C275C43     1          1        1
38158804-3EBC-4841-B1AF-1B86AD153010     2          1        1.1
8E25D494-322F-45F9-8A91-2A385F561C71     3          1        1.1.1
**64EB6C43-FF9C-0FF9-133F-01F4F21DA14F**     4          1        1.1.1.1
13AFA35C-80F8-405A-8980-33C3F7733EE2     2          2        1.2
3F1332E9-4D42-4BD8-9423-598430E94CB5     3          1        1.2.1
B3CC1306-A122-46F6-8F67-30FBABA3B590     4          1        1.2.1.1
C3F27C8E-F96B-4498-A85F-E4FC8EA90ED7     4          2        1.2.1.2
```

This is how it should be looking for the information, the static string are the ones i don't know how to generate in order to get nulls when asking for a level that is not that deep.

```
Select top 1 VehicleGroupId as Region 
      from GroupHierarchy where GroupHierarchy.numericalmapping = '1' 
Select top 1 VehicleGroupId as gz 
      from GroupHierarchy where GroupHierarchy.numericalmapping = '1.1' 
Select top 1 VehicleGroupId as cedis 
      from GroupHierarchy where GroupHierarchy.numericalmapping = '1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting decimals between your hierarchy members rather use forwardslashes (1/2/3) and then you can use Microsoft SQL hiearchy data type and functions to easily join and retain the structure:
https://www.sqlshack.com/use-hierarchyid-sql-server/